# Half-space is not a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

We define the half-space $H^n$ as the set containing all tupels $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ such that all $a_i\geq 0$.

I know that this isn't a manifold - intuitively this is clear - but how can I formally prove it ? I tried to prove the case $n=1$ via contradiction, but couldn't find a way to derive a contradiction, so I'm thinking that there maybe are some calculus facts about continuous maps that I don't know...

Comment: Notice that «such that $a_i\geq0$» is not really enough to describe the set you want: you want that condition to hold for *all* $i$, for *some*?... In the first case, your $H^n$ is not a half space, but what is called an orthant orthant.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, post updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** let $n = 2$ for concreteness, so we get the idea. As you wrote, $H^2$ will be the first quadrant of the cartesian plane. If this is to be a manifold, then it will be at most $2$-dimensional. If you take points $(a_1,a_2)$ with $a_i > 0$ nothing will go wrong, you have neighbourhoods in $H^2$ homeomorphic to disks in $\Bbb R^2$. To see that it is not a $2$-manifold, consider a point, say $(a_1,0)$, with $a_1 > 0$. Is there a neighbourhood of this point, in $H^2$, which is homeomorphic to an *open* disk in $\Bbb R^2$? Try to generalize.

Comment: Well, precisely that is what I didn't manage to prove (albeit for $n=1$): How to derive a contradiction assuming such a neighborhood of $(a_1,0)$ exists.

Comment: A neighbourhood of $(a_1,0)$ in such conditions is not open in $\Bbb R^2$ (why?). Then can it be homeomorphic to an open disk?